# Sorting array of Strings based on array of Doubles

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, exception

So, I want to sort descending the array of doubles, and, accordingly to sort my array of strings. Both of my arrays have the same length.

This is how i do it (adapted from another answer in here):

`arrayS` contains the strings and `array` contains the doubles.

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(arrayS);
Collections.sort(stringList, Comparator.comparing(s -> array[stringList.indexOf(s)]));
```

I am getting out of bounds error on the second line.

More info:

```
System.out.println("arrayS: "+arrayS.length+" array: "+array.length);

out -> arrayS: 125 array: 125
```

Comment: Is `array` the same length as `arrayS`?

Comment: @shmosel yeah and i have double checked it.

Comment: Java is an **Object-Oriented Language**. Use it. Don't use parallel arrays. Define a new class with the two values as fields, then have a single array of those objects. Now the `double` and the `String` values are always paired, so when you sort the array, all is good.

Comment: Btw, sorting `stringList` will also sort the underlying `arrayS`. If that's your intent, you can just sort it directly using `Arrays.sort()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're searching for the elements *while* the list/array is being sorted. That's a recipe for disaster. You need to use one list for index reference and another for sorting:

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(arrayS);
List<String> indexes = new ArrayList<>(stringList);
Collections.sort(stringList, Comparator.comparingDouble(s -> array[indexes.indexOf(s)]));
```

Comment: @Mp.Lo. I'm not sure how you're testing, but it works fine for me: http://ideone.com/jYE3MC

Comment: Just a small remak: You can directly use `stringList.sort(...)` no need for `Collections.sort(...)`. The code works for me too.

Comment: @shmosel I think the output is correct, but when i print the array of double it looks unsorted. But the array of strings looks sorted. hmm i dont get this.

Comment: @Mp.Lo. Why would the double array be sorted? If you want to sort it, you'll have to to so separately: `Arrays.sort(array);`

Comment: Cheers, the thing is that these java shortcuts although they work really nicely, they are pretty 'hard' for novice users to comprehend.

Comment: @Mp.Lo. I'm not sure which "shortcut" you're referring to.

Comment: @shmosel haha, I mean using `collections` / `comparators` ,  etc instead of writing everything from scratch.